# 2000 Buick Century not running after spark plug change

Tags: starting, sparkplugs, buick, century

I had someone come look at my car (big mistake I should have done I it myself). He said the spark plugs needed to be changed and while he was changing them he was revving the engine. He didn't put the spark plugs back correctly. I got the spark plugs in order but now my car will not start. It has power but does not turn over.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Are you sure the engine was running while the person was changing the spark plugs? That sounds like a crazy thing to do. And how do you know the spark plugs were not installed correctly by him? How did you get the plugs "in order"?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to charge your battery then the car will turn over and you can troubleshoot why it's not starting.

You can either

- jump start the car from another car using some jumper cables

OR

- you can put the car on a battery charger to get the battery charged

Once you get it turning over, you can try and figure out the 'will not start' issue.